# Modifying text in a div, but not deleting other elements inside that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a div that looks like this below

```
<div class="registered-count-container">
  <div class="registered-count-inner">@(spaceEvent.IsTeacherRegistered ? "Registered" : "Interested"): <span class="badge">@spaceEvent.RegisteredStudentCount/@spaceEvent.MaxClassSize</span></div>
</div>
```

I want to change text from the div with class 'registered-count-inner' with out deleting the span inside the 'registered-count-container' div, but when I change the text like this

```
$(eventPanel).find(".registered-count-inner").text("Interested");
```

It wipes out everything in the 'registered-count-inner' class including the span with the badge class. Is there a way to change the text without deleting the span tag?

Answer (score 2):

Put that text in another span and change that only:

```
<div class="registered-count-container">
   <div class="">
       <span class="registered-count-inner">@(spaceEvent.IsTeacherRegistered ? "Registered" : "Interested"):</span> 
       <span class="badge">@spaceEvent.RegisteredStudentCount/@spaceEvent.MaxClassSize</span>   

   </div>
</div>
```

And then same code:

```
$(eventPanel).find(".registered-count-inner").text("Interested");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without modifying the markup. Use [`jquery contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) to access the *child nodes* of the element and replace the text of the first text node (in your markup) - see demo below:

```js
$('.registered-count-inner').contents().get(0).nodeValue = 'new text here';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="registered-count-container">
  <div class="registered-count-inner">@(spaceEvent.IsTeacherRegistered ? "Registered" : "Interested"): <span class="badge">@spaceEvent.RegisteredStudentCount/@spaceEvent.MaxClassSize</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are trying to replace the text node present inside you div, you can first filter that text node element and then change its conetnt.

```js
var eventPanel = ".registered-count-container"

var textnode = $(eventPanel).find(".registered-count-inner").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
});

textnode[0].textContent = "Interested"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="registered-count-container">
  <div class="registered-count-inner">Registered <span class="badge"> I am span</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

a more flexible approach

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  
  replaceDivContent('.registered-count-inner', 'Registered', 'Interested');
});

function replaceDivContent(identifier, from, to){

  var newContent = $(identifier).text().replace(from, to);
  $(identifier).text(newContent);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="registered-count-inner">Registered: <span>Other Text Stuff</span></div>
```